# Как начать компилировать с помощью clang

Tags: c++, windows, clang

Установил LLVM 4.0 на Win10
Написал clang++ main.cpp

Мне ответили:

```
fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Что мне конкретно сделать чтобы он видел стандартные заголовки, и не выдавал такие ошибки?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На англиской локали был задан такой вопрос. Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823/clang-doesnt-see-basic-headers)

Comment: Не нашёл, спасибо гляну

Comment: Там это сделано на linux'е, я понимаю что это глупо, но не могли бы вы подсказать что нужно установить вместо g++ на win?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang под windows использует библиотеки времени выполнения от visual studio. Соответственно, вам нужно поставить visual studio и прописать пути к нему. И вам нужен clang-cl, а не clang++. Также есть вариант вместо visual studio использовать MinGW (GCC).

EDIT: вот проверенный вариант:
Для начала нужно скачать [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), можно попробовать поставить vs 2017, но на данный момент clang не компилирует её заголовочные файлы из-за ошибок в них (точнее, для vs это не ошибки, но стандарту они не соответствуют, про это недавно пост на reddit был). Пакеты можно ставить по минимуму, но нужен windows 10/8 sdk.

Далее нужно поставить clang, если уже установлен - активировать скрипт ...\LLVM\tools\msbuild\install (возможно, это не обязательно)

Используемая вами среда разработки уже должна видеть оба компилятора, но для проверки лучше скомпилировать простую программу в консоли. Для этого нужно установить переменные окружения при помощи скрипта, в моём случае это `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64`. Теперь можно использовать как cl, так и clang-cl:

```
mkdir build
cd build
clang-cl ..\main.cpp ..\test.cpp /O2 -o app.exe
app.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же ошибка. Перед этим устанавливал VS preview 2022 которая завершилась с ошибкой. Удалил все VS и установил заново одну VS 2019 CE.

После этого начало компилироваться так:

```
clang hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

или так:

```
clang++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Clang на Windows не самодостаточен. Ему нужны заголовчные файлы, библиотеки, и т. п. от другого компилятора: на выбор GCC (MinGW) или MSVC (Visual Studio).

Поэтому вам нужно установить либо одно, либо другое. Я бы советовал использовать GCC, ради кросс-платформенности (тем же самым способом вы сможете собирать, например на Linux, а также с Linux-а под Windows, если захотите).

Про MSVC рассказывать не буду, там все должно заработать более-менее из коробки.

Если возьмете GCC, то есть несколько вариантов: (отсортированы по удобству, сначала более удобные)

- Ставите не официальный Clang, а сборку из MSYS2 (как это делать см. в конце ответа). Он автоматически установит и GCC тоже. Компилируете командами `clang` и `clang++`, они понимают те же параметры что и GCC.
- Если вдруг с MSYS2 Clang-ом какие-то проблемы, можно поставить в MSYS2 только GCC, и взять официальную сборку Clang-а. Тогда при каждой компиляции вам нужно добавлять флаг `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` (если собираете 32-битное приложение, то замените `x86_64` на `i686`). MSYS2 Clang, в отличие от официального, добавляет этот флаг автоматически.
- Если вам не нравится MSYS2 GCC, то можно поставить любую другую его сборку, например https://winlibs.com/. Единственное требование - установленный GCC нужно добавить в PATH, чтобы Clang его нашел. Все остальное аналогично предыдущему пункту (не забудьте `--target`).

Также, советую попробовать добавлять флаг `-fuse-ld=lld` при линковке, чтобы использовать Clang-овский родной линковщик LLD (вместо LD, который поставляется с GCC). Он намного быстрее (рекламируют 10-кратное ускорение линковки, у меня было 20-кратное...).

Во всех трех описанных выше вариантах, Clang будет использовать стандартную библиотеку C++ от GCC (libstdc++). Для интереса можно попробовать родную Clang-овскую стандартную библиотеку (libc++). На винде она начала работать сравнительно недавно, поэтому могут быть какие-то проблемы. Но зато у вас будет работать [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)... В этом случае LLD используется принудительно, и флаг `-fuse-ld=lld` не нужен. Насколько я знаю, в официальную поставку Clang-а libc++ не входит, поэтому вам нужен MSYS2 Clang. Под это есть отдельная инструкция, см. самый конец ответа.

---

Как ставить MSYS2:

- Качаете [отсюда](https://www.msys2.org/).
- Запускаете ярлыком "MSYS MinGW 64-bit" (он же `C:\msys64\mingw64.exe`). Если сделано правильно, в консоли увидите `MINGW64` розовыми буквами. Если запустить консоль MSYS2 другим способом, то компилятор не окажется в PATH.
- Обновляетесь командой `pacman -Syuu`. Если консоль закроется, перезапустите ее и снова введите ту же команду, чтобы закончить обновление.

  Рекомендуется время от времени обновляться этой командой.
- Дальше ставите нужные вам пакеты, например:

  - GCC: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` (если у вас уже стоит какой-то другой MinGW/GCC, удалите его, чтобы не было никаких проблем)
  - Clang: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-clang` (в этом случае GCC должен установиться автоматически)

  Искать по всем доступным пакетам можно командой `pacman -Ss текст`. Обратите внимание, что все компиляторы и библиотеки должны начинаться с `mingw-w64-x86_64-`. Из пакетов без префиксов можно ставить только консольные утилиты, которые не участвуют в комипляции, а-ля `bash`, `make`. (Объяснение см. [тут](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/).)
- Стоит добавить `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` в `PATH`. Там - все уставновленные в MSYS2 компиляторы.

---

Если хотите использовать libc++ вместо libstdc++, то некоторые шаги отличаются.

- Консоль MSYS2 запускаете файлом `C:\msys64\clang64.exe`. В консоли должно быть написано `CLANG64` розовыми буквами.
- Все пакеты ставите с префиксом `mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-`, например `mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-clang`. GCC в этом случае ставить не нужно, и не получится.